# JMockit converting Array to ArrayList automatically

Tags: java, jmockit

I am mocking a DAO method with a local method in JMockit. The the actual DAO method returns a List where as the local mock method return an array of orders. 
(This was not an intended design, I ended up with this due to negligence while refactoring). But still, this compiles fine and (unfortunately) passes the test case.

Though I later corrected my mock method to match with the actual DAO method, I want to know how could JMockit let me mock that way. How can it not match the return types? Is this a feature or a bug!

```
@Test
    public void testApplyTemplate() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {

            {
                orderDAO.getOrders();
                result = getOrdersMock();
            }
        };
        myService.applyTemplate();
        new Verifications() {

            {
               ...
            }
        };
    }

private Order[] getOrdersMock() {
        Order[] ordersArray = null;
        // create 9 dummy orders, o1 to o9
        orderArray = new Order[] { o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9 };        
        return orderArray;
    }

public interface OrderDAO {

    List<Order> getOrders();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature, and it's described in the [API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#result) for the `result` field (fifth paragraph):

> Assigning a value whose type differs from the method return type will cause an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, unless it can be safely converted to the return type. One such conversion is from an array to a collection or iterator.